# Issue with Running xcode build error : Requested but did not find extension point with identifier

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, dart, xcodebuild

The running xcode build.. is stuck on my Mac M1 when I launch flutter run. Moreover my Mac is getting so hot during the loading of the running which never happen on a mac even if you open all the adobe suite. I don't know what is happening I launched flutter run again and I got this code error :

```
xcodebuild[19990:55573] Requested but did not find extension point with identifier
    Xcode.IDEFoundation.TypeRegistry
    xcodebuild[19990:55573] Requested but did not find extension point with identifier
    Xcode.IDEFoundation.IDEResultKitSerializationConverter
    xcodebuild: error: Existing file at -resultBundlePath
    "/var/folders/5t/74tkj5097ksf5mdlh7f72ncc0000gn/T/flutter_tools.Y88E1D/flutter_ios_build_temp_dirdkk1gE/temporary_xcresult_bundle.xcresult"
```

I also can't start Run and Debug it never works and my mac is boiling when I play it.

Thanks for your help

Comment: did you solve this? Getting the same out of nowhere

Comment: yes i was forgetting to do flutter configure each time after I add a package

Comment: @Boatti how do you do flutter configure?

Comment: @Kevnlan In the terminal